# Possible to mix where() clause

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have the following code (it's shortened otherwise it would be too long to show):

```
Feedback::find()
        ->where(['feedback.fg_id' => $this->id])
        ->orWhere(['feedback.fg_id' => $this->id, 'feedback.closed_time' => NULL, '<' => ['feedback.survey_end_date', new Expression('NOW()')]])
        ->all();
```

This code do not work, because of the last statement in `orWhere()`

My question is now: How can I combine the syntax inside `orWhere`? It's because I need all the statements inside the `or` block.

The ambivalent sql code should be:

```
SELECT * FROM feedback WHERE
(feedback.fg_id = 1) OR (feedback.fg_id = 1 AND feedback.closed_time IS NULL AND feedback.survey_end_date < NOW())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can combine you condition as ...

```
Feedback::find()
->where(['feedback.fg_id' => $this->id])
->orWhere(['AND',
    ['feedback.fg_id' => $this->id],
    ['feedback.closed_time' => NULL],
    ['<' , 'feedback.survey_end_date', new Expression('NOW()')]
 ]);
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your fast response!